# How to loop through list from 2 or more backgroundworker parallel with unique values?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to loop through a list from 2 or more backgroundworker at the same time without select the same values while running??

For example:

we've got 3 backgroundworker

- backgroundworker1
- backgroundworker2
- backgroundworker3

and a List with ints => List Ints = new List() {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

Now i want to iterate through this list without getting the same value of the list at the same time.

Output need to be:

- backgroundworker1 => output 1
- backgroundworker2 => output 2
- backgroundworker2 => output 3
- backgroundworker3 => output 4
- backgroundworker1 => output 5
- backgroundworker2 => output 6
- backgroundworker3 => output 7
- backgroundworker3 => output 8
- backgroundworker1 => output 9
- backgroundworker2 => output 10

Important is to run all backgroundworker at the same time and iterate through a list without getting same value.

How is this possible?

Greets

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `ConcurrentQueue` where you stuff all your numbers. The workers then use `(Try)Dequeue`. Usefull if you continusly stuff numbers in.

Another way is to use `Parallel.ForEach( list, number => { ... worker code here } );`. Best if you have a fixed number of items.

Comment: Thank you @Frank Nielsen it works with ConcurrentQueue :)